# loading a JqGrid on selecting date

Tags: button, jqgrid, click, triggers

I have a datepicker and on selecting the date and clicking button it should display the grid beneath it ...

my approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn:'button',
            buttonImage: '../../image/icon_cal.png',
            buttonImageOnly:true
        });

        jQuery(".submit").click(function(){
            var btnClick = jQuery("#businessError").jqGrid('setGridParam',
              {url:"/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?method=getBusinessErrors"});
        });

        jQuery("#businessError").jqGrid({
            sortable:true,
            url: '/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?method=getBusinessErrors',
            datatype:'json',
            colNames:['Error Number','Error Message','Created date','Created User',
                      'Last Modified Date','Last Modified User'], 
            colModel:[
                { name:'errorNumber',index:'errorNumber', width:80, sorttype:"int",
                  align:"center", key:true },
                { name:'errorMessage',index:'errorMessage', width:280,
                  sorttype:"text", align:"center" },
                { name:'createdDate',index:'createdDate', width:180,
                  sorttype:"text", align:"center" },
                { name:'createdUser',index:'createdUser', width:180,
                  sorttype:"text", align:"center" },
                { name:'lastModifiedDate',index:'lastModifiedDate',
                  width:180, sorttype:"text", align:"center" },
                { name:'lastModifiedUser',index:'lastModifiedUser',
                  width:180, sorttype:"text", align:"center" },
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            jsonReader : {repeatitems: false,
                root: function(obj) {
                    return obj;
                },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            },
            pager: '#businessErrorpager',
            sortname: 'SKU',
            sortorder: "desc",
            loadonce:true,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Business Errors"
          }); 
        jQuery("#businessError").jqGrid('navGrid',
                                        {view:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false});
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

html markup:

```
<div id="header"><jsp:include page="../menu_v1.jsp"/></div>
<div id="mainContent">
  <div id="business_form">
    <form class="dateform" id="date" method="post"
          action="/businessError.do?method=getBusinessErrors">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <legend class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Business Error</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="spogname">Select Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="business">
      <table id="businessError"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
      <div id="businessErrorpager"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It I understand your question correct you should use additional parameters on the server to construct the query filling the jqGrid: startingDate, date, endDate or sothething like that. If the user choose the data in datepicker you can use `setGridParam` to set this additional date parameter as a part of URL or as a part of [postData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) parameter of jqGrid and start `trigger('reloadGrid')`. In general all can work exactly like another external "filter" (see [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819)).

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that the work with datapicker could be a little more simple and without having a form with one more button. You can replace to the following markup

```
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</fieldset>
```

and as a JavaScript code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn:'button'/*,
    buttonImage: '../../image/icon_cal.png',
    buttonImageOnly:true*/
}).bind('change', function(e) {
    var d = e.target.value;
    $("#businessError").jqGrid('setGridParam',
              { url: "/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do",
                postData: {
                    method: "getBusinessErrors",
                    date: d
                },
                page: 1
              }).trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

You server component which listen "/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do" should read an additional parameter "date" which will be the date value from the "datepicker" control. It should send back the data filtered by the data.

Comment: Its just one call I have to make to the server to fetch the data inside the grid...can I just use like this? 

 jQuery(".submit").click(function(){
         jQuery("#businessError").jqGrid('setGridParam',
              {url:"/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?method=getBusinessErrors"});
        });

Comment: It seems to me that you not need use additional "submit" button and not need a form at all. I posted in **"UPDATED"** part short description how it can be done.

Comment: I have to append a parameter say SelDate like /cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?method=getBusinessErrors&SelDate and my server side will fetch the date from that parameter selDate....Can I do like :  var d = e.target.value;
    $("#businessError").jqGrid('setGridParam',
              { url: "/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do",
                postData: {
                    method: "getBusinessErrors&selDate",
                    date: d
                },

Comment: @paul: Yes, you can, but instead of `postData: { method: "getBusinessErrors&selDate", date: d }` it should be `postData: { method: "getBusinessErrors", selDate: d }`. For HTTP GET request `jQuery.ajax` combine the `url` with all parameters from `postData` and use at the end the `url='/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?method=getBusinessErrors&selDate='+d`. Characters '?' and '&' will be added automatically. If some value of parameters from `postData` has special symbols (' ', '/' like can have a date) then the characters will be encoded with `encodeURIComponent` so at the server side will be all OK.